When i add buttons the navigation shifts to the left
I want to keep the navigation in the center, but whenever I add buttons the navigation shifts to the left. How do I keep my navigation centered at all times?
OK so I fixed the problem and used position absolute on .nav-links idk if that's the correct way to do this.


nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px 15px;
  list-style: none;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.logo {
  color: white;
}

.nav-links {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <h3>LOGO</h3>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Eggs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Oats</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Cook</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Cream</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="nav-buttons">
      <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
      <span>|</span>
      <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>




I made you the snippet you could have made using the [<>] snippet editor. I had to close an <a...>  and remove a 

You can use flex or grid
example:


div ul{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}
div ul li {
  margin: 0 10px;
  list-style-type: none
}
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>hi</li> 
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hi</li>
  </ul>
</div>



